# python code for "minute of arc" calculation, completing a latitude and longitude conversion function

Tags: python, dictionary, geolocation, latitude-longitude

"Complete Latitude/Longitude Conversion Function
Humans like to express latitudes and longitudes in degrees, minutes and seconds. You could work with those units in Python, but your computations (and, hence, code) will be much cleaner if you convert to the single unit “degrees”, using fractions of a degree to represent arcminutes and arcseconds.

Your first task will be to fill out the code for the function convert_to_decimal(). The parameters are a latitude (or longitude) in degrees, arcminutes and arcseonds. The function should return the same latitude (or longitude) as a single in decimal degrees (a single value of type float). If you’re not sure how to compute the conversion, do some reading."
link provided: http://www.quickiwiki.com/en/Arcminute

Essentially: trying to get a code that would return the same latitude or longitude as a single in decimal degrees. I understand that I have to convert the value from the inputs given, just trying to find the most efficient way to do that

Comment: Start by writing **any** code to do it - it will be efficient enough ;-)

Comment: well im thinking it should be (degree/60) since "A minute of arc, arcminute, or minute arc (MOA), is a unit of angular measurement equal to one sixtieth (1⁄60) of one degree."

Comment: Eric, you have adequately expression your problem, but you have failed to provide a question. What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break it down, piece by piece.

> > Your first task will be to fill out the code for the function convert_to_decimal().

Do you know how to create a function in Python? We use the `def` keyword to create functions:

```
def convert_to_decimal():
    return 42
```

I have omitted the math, it will come later.

---

> > The parameters are a latitude (or longitude) in degrees, arcminutes and arcseonds.

The function parameters are specified inside the parentheses of the function declaration, like so:

```
def convert_to_decimal(degrees, argminutes, arcseconds):
    return 42
```

---

> > The function should return the same latitude (or longitude) as a single in decimal degrees (a single value of type float).

Let's not forget to document our function, so the python interpreter's `help()` function does something useful:

```
def convert_to_decimal(degrees, arcminutes, arcseconds):
    '''
       Convert degrees, minutes, seconds into the 
       same latitude (or longitude) as a single in
       decimal degrees (a single value of type float)
    '''
    return 42.0
```

The return value should be of type `float`, so I changed our placeholder return statement.

---

> > [From the wiki](http://www.quickiwiki.com/en/Arcminute), An arcminute is ... equal to one sixtieth (1⁄60) of one degree.

And, by extension, an arcsecond is 1/3600 of one degree.

```
def convert_to_decimal(degrees, arcminutes, arcseconds):
    '''
       Convert degrees, minutes, seconds into the 
       same latitude (or longitude) as a single in
       decimal degrees (a single value of type float)
    '''
    return float(degrees + arcminutes/60. + arcseconds/3600.)
```

Notice that I divided by a floating-point constant, not an integer constant, so as to ensure the math is done with floating-point values.